# Como somar um valor de input com um valor já existente? Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu defini um valor inicial para cada informação no gráfico, no caso A,B E C, queria saber como somar com um valor que será colocado no input.

Código do projeto:

```
    <div class="main">
       <chartjs-doughnut v-bind:labels="labels" v-bind:datasets="datasets" v-bind:option="option">
       </chartjs-doughnut>
       <input type="text" id="number1">
       <button @click="soma1()">Colocar</button>
       <input type="text" id="number2">
       <button @click="soma2()">Colocar</button>
       <input type="text" id="number3">
       <button @click="soma3()">Colocar</button>

    </div>
</template>


<script>

    import Motorista from '../services/motoristas'
    import axios from 'axios'

    var A = 5;
    var B = 5;
    var C = 5;

    // function soma1() {
    //     let number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    //     let result = number1 + A.value;
    //     this.A = result;
    // }
    console.log(A)

export default {

    data() {

        return {

            motoristas: [],            

            labels: ["C", "D", "E"],
            datasets: [

                {
                    data: [A, B, C],
                    backgroundColor: ["Red","Yellow","Purple"]
                }
            ],
            option: {
                title: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                text: 'Carteira'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.listar()
        this.soma1()
    },
     methods: {
        listar(){

            Motorista.listar().then(resposta => {
            console.log(resposta.data)
            this.motoristas = resposta.data

            this.categoriaC = this.motoristas.filter(m => m.categoria == 3).length;
            this.categoriaD = this.motoristas.filter(m => m.categoria == 4).length;
            this.categoriaE = this.motoristas.filter(m => m.categoria == 5).length;
            })

        },
        soma1(){
            let number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
            let result = number1 + A.value;
            this.A = result;
        }
   },

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Por favor, quando explicar usar sempre o código todo pois sou inciante em Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legal que esteja aprendendo, então, o **Vue** tem em uma de suas premissas a simplificação do **Javascript**.
Vc pode e na verdade até "deve" declarar tudo que for utilizar dentro da intância do Vue e não fazer como fez, declarar as variáveis **`A,B,C`** fora, isso pode ocasionar muitos problemas no código, vc tbm não precisa pegar os valores dos **inputs** com o javascript, vc pode declarar um **`v-model`** que faz a ligação bidirecional **(html => script, script => html)** dos dados, fora outras coisinhas que irá aprendendo com a prática.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    A: 5,
    B: 5,
    C: 5,
    valor1: '',
    valor2: '',
    valor3: ''
  },

  methods: {

    soma1: function() {
      alert(Number(this.valor1) + this.A);
      console.log('Valor 1: ', this.valor1);
      console.log('Valor A: ', this.A)
    },
    soma2: function() {
      alert(Number(this.valor2) + this.B);
      console.log('Valor 2: ', this.valor2);
      console.log('Valor B: ', this.B)
    },
    soma3: function() {
      alert(Number(this.valor3) + this.C);
      console.log('Valor 3: ', this.valor3);
      console.log('Valor C: ', this.C)
    },
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div class="main" id="app">

  <input type="text" v-model="valor1">
  <button @click="soma1">Colocar</button>
  <input type="text" v-model="valor2">
  <button @click="soma2">Colocar</button>
  <input type="text" v-model="valor3">
  <button @click="soma3">Colocar</button>

</div>
```